# How to get the number of fingers over the Leap Motion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, leap-motion

I want to detect the number of fingers over the leap in C# ...
As a integer 
int fingers;

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
int fingerCount1 = frame.Fingers.Count;
```

Alternatively, you can count the fingers on each hand individually:

```
int fingerCount2 = frame.Hands.Sum(x => x.Fingers.Count);
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is defined as frame.. :( ?

Comment: @RamithHettiarachchi https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/CSharpandUnity/Guides/Leap_Frames.html